# Locating detached DOM tree memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm having trouble diagnosing a detached DOM tree memory leak in a very large single-page web app built primarily with Knockout.

I've tweaked the app to attach a dummy `FooBar` object to a particular HTML button element which should be garbage collected as the user moves to a different "page" of the app.  Using Chrome's *heap snapshot* function, I can see that an old `FooBar` instance (which should have been GC'ed) is still reachable from its `HTMLButtonElement` in a (large) detached DOM tree.

Tracing the references via the *retaining tree* panel, I follow the chain taking decreasing distance from the GC root.  However, **at some point my search reaches a dead end at a node distance 4 from the root** (in this case)!  The retaining tree reports no references to this node at all, yet somehow knows it is four steps from the GC root.

Here is the part of the retaining tree which has me puzzled (the numbers on the right are distances from the root):

```
v foobar in HTMLButtonElement                                  10
  v [4928] in Detached DOM tree / 5643 entries                  9
    v native in HTMLOptionElement                               8
      v [0] in Array                                            7
        v mappedNodes                                           6
          v [870] in Array                                      5
            v itemsToProcess in system / Context                4
                context in function itemMovedOrRetained()
                context in function callCallback()
```

The retaining tree doesn't show the references here at distance 3 or above.

Can anyone explain this to me?  I was hoping I'd be able to follow the reference chain back up to the offending part of the JavaScript app code -- but this has my stymied!

Comment: Can you share some of the code, specifically where this element is created and where it is disposed?

Comment: I'm afraid the code is proprietary and enormous; I haven't had a chance to try reproducing it in the small.  The real issue here is why the Chrome heap profiler should ever report something like the above which doesn't bottom out at the root (how can this be?!).

Comment: You have to remove the property `foobar`(with `delete`; `delete button.foobar` before you remove the `DOM` element and make sure that there are no remaining event listeners.

Comment: @GuyT - thanks for your suggestion, but the point of GC is that I don't need to remove anything that isn't a root to have that thing garbage collected.  My question is "is this a bug in Chrome or, if not, how should I interpret the retaining tree to identify the root pointer causing the memory leak?".

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. At the moment I'm developing a huge SPA with my own framework combined with DOJO. Memory leaks where also a big issue. The most memory leaks where created because I didn't appropriate destroy the connections(event listeners) and I was referencing to other objects(outer scope). After changing my 'normal' objects to the module pattern my leaks where gone. Summarizing; Could you post the code how you create the button with the `foobar` property?

Comment: @GuyT - 'fraid not, the code is proprietary.  We're using Knockout, so there are implicit "event listeners" everywhere.  I still claim that a retaining tree that doesn't reach the root is in error!

Comment: @Rafe But how are we then supposed to help you? The solution is already given: you still have a reference to the object. The GC is counting the remaining references to an object. If it becomes 0 the object will be garbage collected. Otherwise, when it is possible that an object could be called again there will be always a reference. There are many kinds of memory leaks: in closures, circular reference, .. If no code is provided we only can explain you the theory. In earlier days, I've tried to solve memory leaks in a huge app(over 1GB JS),

Comment: but at the end I started from scratch because it's nearly impossible.

Comment: @GuyT, thanks, but I understand the theory: I've written garbage collectors in the past.  I think you may be labouring under a misapprehension.  The *retaining tree* does not count references; it shows distance (by number of links) from the roots (the stack, global variables, etc.).  Anything not reachable from the roots (i.e., anything with a retaining tree whose root node is not at level zero) is garbage and should be collected.  The retaining tree I showed is just such a thing, yet it is not collected.  Hence my belief that there is a bug either in the GC or in the retaining tree display.

Comment: @Rafe Aaah.. I've reread you question and I get your point. Excuse me. I also use the retaining tree a lot and see in your question it never decrement to zero(I missed that). At this point I've to agree with you that it is a possible bug in the GC or the retaining tree. The only thing I'm a bit worried about is that it will be hard to fire a ticket to the Chrome developers because you can't show a code example(patent).

Comment: @GuyT please remember, never use `delete`. It's only useful to remove elements of an object that will be iterated (an object used as a hash table). A reference is removed by assigning `null`. See the demo I linked in my answer. Delete actually wastes memory.

Comment: As a general remark, advanced functions of devtools have plenty of weird, hard to reproduce, bugs. But in this case I'm not even sure what this is.

Answer (score 14):

First of all - do not use `delete` as one of the comments suggested. Setting a reference to `null` is the right way to dispose of things. `delete` breaks the "hidden class". To see it yourself, run my examples from https://github.com/naugtur/js-memory-demo

Rafe, the content you see in profiler is often hard to understand. The bit you posted here does seem odd and might be a bug or a memory leak outside of your application (browsers leak too), but without running your app it's hard to tell. Your retaining tree ends in a context of a function and it can be retained by a reference to that function or some other function sharing the context. It might be too complicated for the profiler to visualize it correctly.

I can help you pinpoint the problem though.

First, go to Timeline tab in devtools and use it to observe the moment your leak happens. Select only memory allocation and start recording. Go through a scenario that you expect to leak. The bars that remain blue are the leaks. You can select their surrounding in the timeline and focus on their retaining tree. The most interesting elements in detached dom trees are the red ones - they're referenced from the outside. The rest is retained because whatever element in a tree is referenced, it has references to everything else (`x.parentNode`)

If you need more details, you can take multiple snapshots in the profiler, so that you have a snapshot before and after the cause of the leak (that you found with the timeline - you now know the exact action that causes it). You can then compare those in the profiler - there's a "compare" view. which is more comprehensible than others.

You can also save your heap snapshots from the profiler and post them online, so we could take a look. There's a save link on each of them in the list to the left.

---

Profiling memory is hard and actually requires some practice and understanding of the tools.
You can practice on some examples from my talk:

http://naugtur.pl/pres/mem.html#/5/2

but the real complete guide to using memory profiler is this doc:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#looking_up_color_coding

**Updated link:** https://developers.google.com/web/tools/profile-performance/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis

Comment: Many thanks for this!  We're rather busy at the moment, but I will try your suggestions as soon as I have a spare afternoon.  Glad to see someone agreeing with me that the trace looks very odd.

Comment: Nodes highlighted yellow have direct references to them from the JavaScript code. Nodes highlighted red do not have direct references. They are only alive because they are part of the yellow node's tree. In general, you want to focus on the yellow nodes. Fix your code so that the yellow node isn't alive for longer than it needs to be, and you also get rid of the red nodes that are part of the yellow node's tree.

Comment: But what if you only have red nodes?

Comment: @Legends some here. I have also some problems with node count and only red highlighted detached nodes.