# Detached DOM trees in single page application

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, google-chrome-devtools, single-page-application

I am working on a mobile app that is built as a single page application using KnockoutJS and RequireJS and currently trying to solve some app crashes on iOS.

During my investigation, while profiling the app's memory utilization using Chrome Developer Tools, I noticed a large amount of Detached DOM trees.  I simplified the application to just the Knockout related code to try to isolate the problem but even with the simplest example of the initialization I still get detached DOM trees.

[image: Heap profile snapshot]

Is it acceptable and normal to have these present in the DOM?
Is there something I can do to get rid of them and will it help app performance?

Here is the code for the very simple app that produces the above Heap profile using Chrome Developer Tools: [SPA.git](https://github.com/mwridgway/SPA.git)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226646/locating-detached-dom-tree-memory-leak

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks I've been through that, although this scenario is happening after initialization before doing anything in the browser.

Comment: Are you using components or templates? They could be waiting in reserve.

Comment: @RoyJ In the example in the git repo, I've made a component that has a template and a view model.  What do you mean by waiting in reserve, is there some documentation you can refer me to wrt how that works?  As far as I understand, the items in the detached DOM trees view from Chrome developer tools have no Javascript references, so are seemingly unusable and mean they are leaked..

Comment: I'm afraid we're already beyond my level of expertise. I was guessing that Knockout, if you're using templates, might keep the templates as doctrees to copy/instantiate.